# What is the difference (if any) between an Intrinsically Disordered Protein and an Intrinsically Disordered Region

Tags: molecular-biology

The wikipedia definition of an Intrinsically Disordered Protein is a protein that lacks a specific 3D structure.  An Intrinsically Disordered Region is similarly defined.  Why are they often listed separately?  Isn't an Intrinsically Disordered Protein just a protein that has at least one Intrinsically Disordered Region?

Just a couple examples:

https://doi.org/10.1002/pro.3680

> In contrast to structured proteins, intrinsically disordered
> proteins and regions (IDPs and IDRs)

https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.biophys.37.032807.125924

> There are a number of significant differences between the amino acid sequences of IDPs/IDRs and those of structured globular proteins and domains.

Comment: This is surely just plain English. Assuming the explanation in the Wikipedia article is that generally accepted, an IDR is a  disordered region within an IDP, which may have have ordered regions as well as disordered regions (as in the animated illustration). I don’t see your problem. A region is a part of a larger entity. If the whole protein is disordered, then all its regions are, but you can’t talk about the whole protein as a region. (I assume from your name that you are a native English speaker.)